# rdd action will be suspended in DStream foreachRDD function

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have encountered with error :  rdd action will be suspended in DStream foreachRDD function.

Please refer to the following code.

```
import _root_.kafka.common.TopicAndPartition
import _root_.kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata
import _root_.kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._


object StreamingTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))

    val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "localhost:9092")

    val topicOffset = Map(TopicAndPartition("test_log",0)->200000L)
    val messageHandler = (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => mmd.message
    val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String,String,StringDecoder,StringDecoder,String](ssc,kafkaParams,topicOffset,messageHandler)

    kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd=>{
      println(rdd.count())
      val collected = rdd.collect()
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

**Error:**

The function `rdd.count()` or `rdd.collect()` will be suspended.

I am using `spark` version is 1.4.1.

Am I using it in a wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: are you running spark in cluster mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we didn't set the maxRatePerPartition from kafka, it will try to read all data, so it will be look like suspended. But it actually busy at reading data.

After I set the following configuration

```
spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=1000
```

It will print log.